# How do the sniper rifle modifications work?

Tags: mass-effect-3

1. If I'm a soldier or infiltrator, can I get an even higher level of time dilation during scoping by adding the concentration mod for the sniper rifle?
2. Does the sniper rifle clip size mod round up or down?  If I have a Mantis and I put in a 70% clip size mod, will I now have 2 shots or still 1?
3. How exactly does the extended scope mod work with smoke, will it let me see through it or does it highlight targets inside smoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the concentration mod will stack with the Infiltrator's Operational Mastery, or the Soldier's Adrenaline Rush.
2. The Spare Thermal Clip upgrade increases your overall ammo capacity for the rifle, but doesn't impact the clip size. So, in the case of the Mantis, your clip size will always be one. Your spare ammo capacity, on the other hand, will be increased by the given percentage, rounded down (need to verify the rounding, but memory-maths tells me this is the case).
3. The Extended Scope upgrade highlights targets within the smoke, using an orange/red outline. I found this had mixed success depending on how close the target was to the smoke, since sometimes they would fade out of view.

Answer (score 2):

Both the concentration mod and adrenaline rush (soldier) or operational mastery (infiltrator) stack.

This is on the ME wiki under weapon mods/sniper concentration mod.
Slows time briefly when zooming in. (Stacks with Adrenaline Rush and Operational Mastery).

[This](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_Upgrades_%28Mass_Effect_3%29#Sniper_Rifle_Concentration_Module_.28Single_Player_only.29) is the link to the site this information is pulled from.

Both of the other mods you mention are below, however they don't clearly state the answer you are looking for, so unless it is tested we cannot find out.

The sniper clip I think can be tested at the target practice, however the smoke grenade would require real combat to test.

Answer (score 1):

1. To put it simply Samuels correct, but if you want to get into more technical terms the concentration mod is connected to your brain somehow and increases concentration by increasing hormone production or creating more bioelectrical currents.

2.I am almost certain it rounds down.

3.It highlights the target like if you were targeting him.